# bootstrap: how to push down contents below a dropdown menu on a sidebar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to bootstrap, html, css, and no knowledge on javascript.

I was able to create a sidebar that includes a dropdown. The default dropdown for bootstrap, when toggled/opened, covers the contents below it. Like this...

[image]

However, I want something like the one in SB Admin where it pushes down the content below it instead of covering it. Like this...

[image]

I'm wondering how I can do that, without adding the whole SB Admin theme/template into my project, if possible, copying only the part of it that performs the dropdown effect that i want.

Comment: StartBootstrap isn't using a dropdown - you simply toggle a hide/show class on nested lists. An example would be http://www.bootply.com/uBoT3zP1P2

Comment: @TiesonT. thanks! I wasn't aware that nested lists could be done that way

Comment: Here's a vertical nav example: http://www.bootply.com/OPbQbMdQk9